# MobaXterm - Errors regarding missing DLLs

Tags: windows, dll, mobaxterm

I installed MobaXterm home edition v22.1 on a Windows10 64 bit laptop.
The installation completed successfully, but when I run the software, I get a bunch of errors regarding missing DLLs:
[image]

After that, the software is stuck and I can't click anything. This happens about 30 sec after starting the software, even if no session is started.
I've tried removing and re-installing, using both the installer and the portable editions, but still getting the same errors.
Any idea why this is happening and how to fix?
BTW, sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question. Please direct me to the right site.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the version from
[this page](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html)
and installed it. I had no such problems with running it and all your
missing DLLs are found correctly in the installation folder.

I suggest to uninstall your version, perhaps with an uninstaller like
[Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/)
which will clean up all traces of the previous installation, and reboot.
Then download again from my page and install.

If you are still encountering these errors, perhaps your Windows setup
needs to be checked. If you have any other antivirus installed than
Windows Defender, then it might be erroneously deleting or blocking
these DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider the previous stable version in v22.0. I should think [MobaXterm's portable](https://download.mobatek.net/2202022022680737/MobaXterm_Portable_v22.0.zip) would preclude the issues you are experiencing, but there is still [the local installer for v.22.0](https://download.mobatek.net/2202022022680737/MobaXterm_Installer_v22.0.zip), if you so choose.

Additionally, you might consider [the preview candidate](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/preview.html) to include "the latest features and improvements," to see if your unobstructed use fares better.

The alternative, downloading the missing libraries from vetted sources and copying them into expected directories or even linking to existing libraries on your PC is possible, I believe, however cumbersome and potentially risky.

In the case of the installed versions, of course it's advisable to uninstall your present version of MobaXterm with a potential restart before installing any other versions of the software. Disabling antivirus and malware applications before install is usually suggested. Hopefully, these considerations might assist you to get a working version of the application on your machine with the least amount of trouble.